# Adding Brackets and comma at the end for the text file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file  that looks like this:

```
5,1730572382,8236,1600956334,12.95,1012.38,64.80   
6,1730551647,8266,1600956334,13.42,1012.43,64.66   
7,1730582880,8290,1600956334,13.18,1012.60,61.39
```

I want the text file to look like this

```
[5,1730572382,8236,1600956334,12.95,1012.38,64.80],  
[6,1730551647,8266,1600956334,13.42,1012.43,64.66],   
[7,1730582880,8290,1600956334,13.18,1012.60,61.39],
```

how can I achieve this in python. I searched but can only find how to remove brackets not add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read file by lines. Then add your desired string to each line. At last, write to file.

```py
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('processed.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines([''.join(['[', line.strip(), '],\n']) for line in lines])
```

Content of `processed.txt`:

```
[5,1730572382,8236,1600956334,12.95,1012.38,64.80],
[6,1730551647,8266,1600956334,13.42,1012.43,64.66],
[7,1730582880,8290,1600956334,13.18,1012.60,61.39],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('file.txt').read()
print([[float(i) for i in line.split(',')] for line in file.splitlines()])
```